# Universal Package Managers - is MyGet oddly cheap

Tags: repository, package-managers

My organization needs a central place to keep our binaries across the different engineering teams. Currently we deal solely with npm and nuget packages. We will want to host our own private npm and nuget feeds and will want caching (which comes with these package managers - universal package managers aren't a factor correct?) to be available.

As I research the different commercial suppliers of such services, I have come across:

- MyGet
- ProGet
- JFrog Artifactory
- Package Drone
- Nexus

This link has been very helpful:
https://binary-repositories-comparison.github.io/

What I have come down to is MyGet seems to offer everything I need, however so does ProGet and Artifactory. Although both the latter two are thousands of dollars more than the MyGet platform. I can't figure out why? Can someone help me understand what I am missing here... I am still learning about this world of repo managers.

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question (tool/service recommendation) is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it will just lead to opinion, discussion, and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to reach out to MyGet if you have any questions/use cases you are looking at. (http://myget.org/support)